# Why is あるうちに correct but 残るうちに is not?

Tags: grammar

This question comes from 新完全マスター文法N2:

```
(    )うちに欲しい物を買っておこう。

1. お金がある
2. 給料をもらう
3. お金が残る
```

The second answer seems pretty obviously incorrect to me, but I'm not sure why #1 is correct yet #3 is not. They both seem to have the same meaning. Is there some subtle distinction that allows only #1 to fit here? Does 残る perhaps only imply that there is money left short-term? (for example, the difference between "there is no money left in my pocket right now" and "I'm penniless and going to lose my home").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ある is a verb describing a state. もらう and 残る aren't stative verbs.

The phrase ～うちに needs to be connected to a stative verb, like いる and then it would make sense.

> 給料{きゅうりょう}をもらって**いる**うちに
>
> お金{かね}が残{のこ}って**いる**うちに

For a comparison in English I think about the difference between hire, fire and employ.

```
Hired ⇒ Employed ⇒ Fired
```

1. When you get hired by a company, that's something that happens once and then its over. *Your hired!*
2. Then *you're employed* by the company, which is a state that you're in for a period of time.
3. Then BAM! *You're fired!* (*cobra hand gesture) This also happens once and your state of employment is over.

Comment: I'm not sure about this analogy with English. You can't be fired 50%, but you can potentially make 30 payments and if after each one money will remain - it somewhat describes the state/condition of having enough.

Comment: What you say makes sense for my question but leaves me a little uncertain why "溶けないうちに" (from an example in the book) is correct given your statement on the second line ("The phrase..."). So are verbs always considered stative in their negated form or does "xないうちに" require a different explanation altogether?

Comment: "hired" doesn't necessarily refer to once. it is perfectly proper to say "while you're hired..."

Comment: @Aurast I think 溶けないうちに makes sense because ない is the opposite of ある and is treated sort of like an adjective. 熱いうちに would be correct as well.

Comment: @macraf I agree. And you could purchase something while you still had money remain-ing. Know what I mean? （お金が残る・お金が残っている）

Comment: @A.Ellett Can you be half-hired? I'm not sure it's correct English. If you do a Google search for "while you're hired" in quotes, I think you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @sazarando you're comment makes no sense. I'm just pointing out that in English (and as a native speaker i should know) it makes perfect sense to say "while hired" or "while married" or any number of similar things. i dont see why you bother mentioning "half" anything.

Comment: @A.Ellett I'm interested in what a full sentence would be like for "while hired". Could you give an example?

Comment: Well, actually I am still not convinced with the explanation. 練習を重ねるうちに is perfectly grammatical, isn't it? That's not a verb describing state. Don't you have to consider what follows?

Comment: @sazarando "While hired, you will adhere company policy on drug use", just like "while married, you should remain faithful to your spouse."   At any rate, my point is that "hired" is not in a moment but may potentially cover the state of employment itself.

Comment: @macraf Yes, I think you're right... 練習を重ねるうちに is just fine... Hmmm, any ideas? I'll be happy to amend my post if we can think of something....

Comment: @A.Ellett I don't think I've ever seen "hire" used like that before... Can you find a quote from a newspaper or dictionary to show that usage? I see what you're saying about married though, but that kind of implies a state the same way that employed does, right?

Comment: @sazarando I have no idea, I just hear うちに being used with non-stative verbs in plain form. And 重なる, 貯まる, 残る look to me like having similar function in sentences.

Comment: 「練習を重ねるうちに」の「うちに」は、ちょっと意味が違います。「お金が残っているうちに」「お金があるうちに」などは、「while+状態」ですけど、「練習を重ねるうちに」は「練習を重ねていくと/重ねるにつれ、ますます/どんどん~~」「As+動作, ~~more」のニュアンスがあります。ここの「日本語を勉強して行くうちに日本に関する色々なことが分かって来た。 」が他の例文と少し違っているのが、参考になるかもしれません。→　http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=uchini

Comment: @chocolate 「日本語を勉強するうちに日本に関する色々なことが分かって来た。 」はどう感じられますか？

Comment: 自然な文だと思います。「お金があるうちに/残っているうちに/お給料をもらっているうちに～～する」の「うちに」(= "While/Before~~") ではなく、"As~~, ~~ gradually~~ / more~~" (勉強していると/勉強するにつれ、だんだん/ますます～してくる) という感じがします。